# An segmentfault example in C, but I don't know how to explain

Tags: c

```
int i = 123;
printf("%s\n", i);
```

I think the complier treats i as the beginning of a string, and trys to find the '\0' to terminate. The process space is read only, so I think it will run successfully. But it prints nothing, and terminated with segmentfault 11.

Comment: Usually when you printf a string you send it an address location.  You are essentially telling it to look in position 123 of memory for the string, which more than likely is out of your assigned scope and causing the segfault

Comment: And you think an integer is a string . . . why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's crazy.  Even the OP knows it's crazy, but does it anyway:(

Answer (score 2):

Your program tried to interpret `123` as a memory address at which to find a string, as specified by the format `%s`.  If you want to print an integer, use `%d` instead.

What you are getting right now is *undefined behaviour*, and that is the explanation for why the behaviour is not as you expect.

Comment: This is a question that an interviewer asked me. I know if I want to print an integer, and I can use %d instead. I really want to know where is the space of 123. Is it in the text segment? Is it read protection？

Comment: It depends on the compiler and the architecture.  The thing is that your program did not acquire the pointer via legitimate means and so the behaviour is undefined.  If the interviewer is expecting an answer different from this then it's an unfair question and you probably shouldn't work for them.

Comment: @JianjiaZhang: Typically the first page of virtual memory isn't mapped anywhere, so it's not contained in any segment.  If 123 was a valid address, 0 (NULL) would also be a valid address.  Most code assumes NULL is not a valid address, so trying to use the memory in that page would be really inconvenient.  (`wine` and `dosemu` sometimes find it useful to map the first page, but I forget why.  See `/etc/sysctl.d/10-zeropage.conf` on GNU/Linux systems, which typically sets `vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536` to prevent NULL-dereference attacks.)